# ValueError : The given username should be set

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to write my method to add a User type object on registration. Here is the code:

views.py

```
def registration(request):
c= {}
c.update(csrf(request))
state = "Please Register below..."
username = None
email = None
password = None
user_success = None
user_created = None
if request.POST:
    username = request.POST.get('username')
    email = request.POST.get('email')
    password = request.POST.get('password')
    print "username ",username

user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
if user is not None:
    if user.is_active:
        user_created = True
    else:
        user_created = False
else:
        user = User.objects.create_user(username=username,password=password,email=email)
        user.save()
        user.is_active = True
        user_success = True

return render_to_response('register.html',{'success':user_success,'created':user_created,'username': username},context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

forms.py

```
class RegistrationForm(forms.Form):

username = forms.CharField()
email = forms.EmailField()
password =  forms.CharField()
```

templates/register.html is:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block pageContent %}
<div class="container">


    <form action="/register" method="post">

            {% csrf_token %}
            username:
            <input type="text" name="username" value="{{ username}}" /><br />
            password:
            <input type="password" name="password" value="" /><br />
            Email:
            <input type="text" name="email" value="{{email}}" /><br />

            <input type = 'submit' value='Register' />
    </form>


</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Can anyone please help me spot the error? Also let me know if I am doing the registration right

Answer (score 1):

The value of `username` at this point must evaluate to True.

```
user = User.objects.create_user(username=username,password=password,email=email)
#                                        ^^^^^^^^ this can't be a bool() false
```

Why? That error message is very specific.. it's called from [this specific place](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L179) in django auth:

```
  def create_user(self, username, email=None, password=None, **extra_fields):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given username, email and password.
        """
        now = timezone.now()
        if not username:
            raise ValueError('The given username must be set')
```

Can you be 100% positive username is the right value? It sounds like it's an empty string.

Comment: I found the error. The error was in indentation of the view.py. `if user is not None` part of the code should be only if the request type is POST. So that needed indentation. Thanks for trying to help

Answer (score 0):

I found the error. The error was in indentation of the view.py.

```
if user is not None:
```

part of the code should be only if the request type is POST. So that needed indentation.